# How can I use the OnRender event but only render to the control area in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, render

**Background:**
I am converting a control from WinForms to WPF. In WinForms I overrode a PictureBox and used the `OnPaint` event to draw what I needed to that control. That control would handle all the double-buffering and clipping.

I converted the control to WPF and am inheriting from Canvas now. I am overriding the `OnRender` event and drawing everything to the DrawingContext, but it looks like the DrawingContext allows me to draw past the control onto the rest of the view:

[image: Render example]

In the above image the solid dark pink box is the control and the light pink box and green line are drawn at (0, 0), but the blue box is drawn at (0, -100).

In WinForms the PictureBox would clip whatever was not in the control's region.

Also, I found that the blue box does get clipped if the box falls below the control. I assume that is because it does clip below the enclosing Grid, but I'm not sure.

**Questions:**

1. What exactly is the DrawingContext doing and why can I draw past my
   control?
2. How do I achieve the same functionality with correct
   clipping in WPF? Do I need to override a different function, draw a different way, or is there
   some way I can limit the drawing in the `OnRender` method of my
   control to the specific region?
3. Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do (arbitrary drawing to a control with correct clipping and double-buffering)?

I tried adding shapes to the Canvas children, but this is extremely slow.

Comment: Just a note: in order to implement custom rendering by overriding OnRender you don't need to derive from Canvas. FrameworkElement or even UIElement should be sufficient. However, you'll need to set ClipToBounds to true.

Comment: @Clemens, will it handle double-buffering if I override either of those? In WinForms if I overrode a Panel control there was no double buffering, but a PictureBox had double-buffering taken care of in the control. I will be using this control like a CAD view allowing the user to move and change things inside it with scaling and panning, etc.

Comment: There is no (built-in) double buffering in WPF. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1672595/1136211).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is related to how Canvas renders stuff. That means its children can be rendered outside its actual region. However you can avoid that default behavior by setting the property 
 `ClipToBounds` to `true`:

```
yourCanvas.ClipToBounds = true;
```